# 2D arraylist to keep a point

Tags: java, arraylist

i made a program that whenever i click my mouse, it draws a circle in the point that i clicked,
now i want it to check if there is already a circle in the point that i am clicking , and if there is then i want to delete that circle.
i thought to do it with a 2D arralist that will keep all the points already taken, can anyone show me how do i do it?
this is my code so far:

```
public class delta extends Applet implements MouseListener  {

private Graphics globalg;

public void init(){
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    this.setSize(new Dimension (1000, 1000));
    globalg = g.create();
}



public void draw(int x, int y , int width , int height){


    globalg.setColor(getColor());
    Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double((double) x , (double) y ,(double) width , (double) height);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) globalg;
    g2.fill(circle);

}


public Color getColor(){

    int r = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    int g = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

    return new Color(r , g ,b);
}



@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();

    draw(x , y , 20 , 20);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: "show me how to do it", is the kind of question, which leads to downvotes, lower quality answers or no answers at all. What have you already tried? What are your problems? Do you want to delete from exact values or should the circle disappear if the click is within the circle

Comment: What is a "2D `ArrayList`"?

Answer (score 0):

I won't be telling you exactly what to do, but I'll get you in the right direction.

**Step one - Your Data Structure**

Now, I can see why you wanted to use a nested `ArrayList` for this, but conceptually this isn't very nice. You can represent a matrix of values without a complex data structure by enclosing the relevant values inside an `Object`. Now, you *could* make your own object or you can use the Java `Point` class. For the purposes of this, we'll make your own object so you can easily add your own values (colour, size, etc).

```
public class MyCircle {
}
```

And in there, you can store your `x` and `y` positions. These can then be stored into a `List`, so your `MyCircle` objects will  be accessed via something like:

```
private List<MyCircle> circles;
```

**Step Two - Handling Mouse Clicks**

You've already implemented the `MouseListener` interface, so we're in a good place to get building on that. Now, the way I see it, there are two possibilities that you need to account for when handling a mouse click.

- No Circle exists and you need to draw one.
- A Circle exists and you need to delete it.

*No Circle Exists*

If no circle exists, then you draw it. You seem to have got this bit handled so there's no sense explaining it.

*A Circle Exists*

This is where you've stopped. So, first things first, you'll need to traverse your data structure, which we've named `circles`..

```
for(MyCircle circle : circles) {
}
```

Now, I'll assume you've got something like `x` and `y` in here, a long with the relevant accessors and mutators. You then can check the co-ordinates..

```
if(circle.getX() == x && circle.getY() == y) {
    // A circle was put at this point..
}
```

***NOTE:*** This will make it quite hard to delete a circle. What you really want is to be able to check if the use has clicked *inside* a circle! How do you do this? Well, that's about comparing the values. You want to make sure that the user clicked at an `x` value that is larger than the `x` value of the circle, but smaller than `x + width` of the circle. Likewise, you want to make sure the user also clicked at a `y` value that is larger than the `y` value of the circle, but smaller than `y + width` of the circle.

```
if(x > circle.getX() && x < (circle.getX() + circle.getWidth())) {
    // This was a click inside the circle on the X axis. Your turn to check the y!
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, but how do i delete the circle? after i check if where i clicked is a circle as u showed me, what do i do now to delete the circle?

Comment: Remove it from the list. When you repaint, it will not be rendered.